# How to set and retrieve items to/from an array that is stored in smart contract memory/storage?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to add msg.value and msg.sender into an array using web3 for every client that invokes my contract. I would like this information to be stored on the contract for as long as possible, if possible.

If a new client invokes this method, they are added to the array, and so on.

I then want to be able to retrieve those values (msg.value, msg.sender) from the array via web3 at a later point in time.

It would be great to see the contract code, and the web3 code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Set and retrieve to/from array: http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html#arrays

To retrieve array values through web3, write a function in the contract that returns the values (see above example) and then call it with: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall

Comment: Answers should be clear and useful even if all the links are broken. please include a summary of each source or a code snippet